# How to disable / remove / unbind a jQuery Overlay?

Tags: jquery, overlay, jquery-tools, unbind

I create a jQuery Tool's Overlay on a trigger as such:

```
$('button').overlay(
{
 ... 
});
```

How can I disable and re-enable the overlay later on ?  I want my `$('button')` element to remain as a link, but instead of displaying the Overlay on click, I want to show an alert ?

Something like that :

```
if( needToDisableOverlay() )
{
   $('button').overlay().disable(); // no such thing...
   $('button').bind( 'click.alert', function()
   {
      alert( 'The overlay has been disabled' );    
   });
}
// later on
if( needToEnableOverlay() )
{
    $('button').unbind( 'click.alert' );
    $('button').overlay().enable(); // no such thing...
}
```

I know I can use

```
$('button').unbind('click');
```

to remove *all* click handlers from the button (including the Overlay **load()** function), but I don't think this is a clean way of doing it especially if I have other click handlers I want to maintain.

Maybe I can use flag in the Overlay's **onBeforeLoad** handler and return false if the flag is set ?

What is the proper of achieving this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

> Maybe I can use flag in the Overlay's **onBeforeLoad** handler and return false if the flag is set ?

This works nicely, and looks clean.  No unbinding required.

I guess I should have tried before posting -- then again, maybe this will help other people in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any reference to unbinding/destroying an overlay in the jQuery Tools documentation.

But why don't you use a second button for your alert link and simply toggle the display of the 2 buttons? That way you don't have to do anything about the binding.

Comment: True, I hadn't thought about this.  I like it.

Answer (score 0):

To deactivate an overlay link, I add a class `overlay-disabled` to the trigger-link:

```
$('#overlay-button').addClass('overlay-disabled');
```

In the `onBeforeLoad` handler I check the triggering element for this class:

```
onBeforeLoad: function() {
    if (this.getTrigger().hasClass('overlay-disabled')) return false;
    // ...
}
```